# NSSpeechSynthesizer and track duration

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, text-to-speech

This time I have a logic question. Hope someone of you could help me. Using the `NSSpeechSynthesizer' you can set the rate, i.e. 235 words per minute, 100 words per minute and so on...

I found that generally the average of words per minute is calculated using standardized word length of 5 characters per word, counting spaces and symbols too.

I need to automatically subdivide a long text in tracks with a pre-selected duration, let say 15 minutes per track.

How can we calculate the correct number of characters to pass for each 'split' to the speech engine?

My solution is as follow:

```
// duration is the number of minutes per track
numberOfWordsPerTrack = [rateSlider floatValue] * duration;
splits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

finished = NO;
NSUInteger position = 0;
while( !finished ) {
    NSRange range;

    // the idea is: I take 5*numberOfWordsPerTrack characters
    // until the text allows me to select them  
    range = NSMakeRange( position, 5*numberOfWordsPerTrack );
    if( range.location+range.length > mainTextView.string.length ) {
        // If there are not another full character track we get
        // the tail of the remaining text 
        finished = YES;
        range = NSMakeRange( position, mainTextView.string.length-position );
    }

    // Here we get the track and add it to the split list  
    if( range.location+range.length <= mainTextView.string.length ) {
        currentSplit = [mainTextView.string substringWithRange:range];
        [splits addObject:currentSplit];
    }

    position += range.length;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the track duration is not correct. It is not quite far from the desired value, but it is not right. For example, using 235 words per minute with duration of 50 minutes, I have 40 minutes per track. If I set 120 minutes per track, I have 1h:39m per track... and so on...

Where do you think is the logic error?

***EDIT AFTER JanX2 REPLY***

Well, while randomly thinking I came to the following hypotesis Could you tell me what do you think about that before its implementation, because it is not a light change in my code

If I used the `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:` delegate member I could test the .aiff file size frequently, i.e. before speaking the next word (real word, not standardized). Because we know the Hzs, bits and channels those file are created with by synthesizer and because we know they are not compressed, we could gain some guess about the current length of the track.

The biggest drawback of this solution could be che continuous disk access, that can highly degrade performance.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, but the heuristic you use will include “silent” characters. Why not try an compensate for the measured error? You appear to have an error that is pretty much linear so you could factor that into your calculation:

40 / 50 = 80%
99 / 120 = 82.5%

So you have an error of about 17.5-20%. Just multiply the time you calculate above by 0.8 or 0.825 and you are getting closer. This is crude, but you are already using a heuristic.

BTW: You probably should consider using `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` to achieve sentence granularity instead of arbitrary word splits.

Using “-speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:” causes bigger issues: in my experience it can be out of sync with the position in the file being written by several hundred ms up to several seconds. And speaking up the next word seems to have problems when used with the Nuance voices.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much fur suggestion. Could you be a little bit more specific about the compensation method you suggested? You know that when you call startspeakingString:toURL, you can not monitor the time the .aiff is going to be...

Comment: While this is true, you can use the lower level CoreFoundation-based API to stream the audio into a buffer and regularly write that to a new file. It’s a lot of work though.